# Why is this simple piece of code not working?

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I am trying to get a floating variable accurate to just 3 decimal points for a comparison calculation. I am trying the method below, but it doesn't work. I can't see why not, so please can someone tell me where I am going wrong.

Output from this code is `b = 10000.050617, bb = 10000050 and fbb = 10000.000`. I want fbb to be 10000.050.

```
int bb; double m,n,p,q,b,t,u,fbb;

m=24.161, n=57.695, p=67.092, q=148.011;
t=p-m; u=q-n;
b=t*t+u*u; bb=b*1000; fbb=bb/1000;

printf("b=%.6lf,bb=%i,fbb=%.3lf\n",b,bb,fbb);

return 0;
```

Comment: Dividing 2 integers (bb/1000) the result integer. change bb to double

Comment: @ctheo No need to convert bb to double. It will work with int too when typecasted as double while dividing.

Comment: You may not be able to perform the desired comparison this way, for several reasons involving the nature of floating-point arithmetic. The values to be compared may have rounding errors from previous operations. Attempting to round them to three decimal digits may introduce further errors. Comparing for equality after rounding may report as different numbers that are actually extremely close to each other but lie on different sides of the point where rounding changes. What is the larger problem you are attempting to solve?

Comment: Thanks guys.  What I want is to take 2 floating point numbers and compare them to 3 decimal point.  For example, 123.456789 in my calc is the same as 123.456111. So, my thinking is 123.456789 times 1000 'integerised' is 123456 and the same for 123.456111. Then, dividing by 1000.0 will give 123.456 for both and they will be equal in my calc.

Answer (score 5):

`bb` is an `int`, so `bb / 1000` will follow the integer division. Change either or both operand to a `double`. The simplest way is:

```
fbb = bb / 1000.0;       //type of 1000.0 is double
```

or

```
fbb = (double)bb / 1000
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is the simplest solution.

Answer (score 5):

When you perform

```
 fbb = bb/1000;
```

It treats operation as `int/int` and returns an `int`

Try

```
fbb = ((double)bb)/1000.000;
```

It will be treated as `(double)/(double)` and return a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform

```
fbb = bb/1000;
```

It treats operation as int/int and returns an int. its demotion of value.

Also take `long bb;` instead of int as int has value 32767 as its high value.

Try

```
fbb = bb/1000.000;
```

or

```
fbb = (double)bb/1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

`bb` is int. So `bb/1000` is doing a int division, which results again in an int = 1000 (no decimals). That int value is cast to a double.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
fbb=(double)bb/1000;
```

bb is integer and result is integer, and then converted to double